# Grails 1.3.7 - multi tenant plugin and multi threading operation - thread cannot access to tenant

Tags: multithreading, grails, grails-plugin, multi-tenant, grails-domain-class

As you can understand by the title my situation is:

- I'm using a very old version of Grails (I can not change it at the moment)
- In this project I'm using multitenant plugin, in detail i've installed

  - multi-tenant-core:1.0.3
  - multi-tenant-ehcache:1.0.1
- I want split a method (it takes 2-3 minutes to execute it) and parallelize the operations.

Here is my code:

```
def threadPoolSize = 10 
def threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize)

def threadClosure = { myWork ->
    def partialQuantity = 0
    myWork.each { currDetail ->
       MyTableDomainClass.findByCode(currDetail.myTableCode)
       // Do some stuff
    }
    return partialQuantity
}

try{
    def worksForThreads = new ArrayList<org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray>(10) 

    // Prepare works for thread
    Integer x = 0
    allWorks.each{ singleOrder -> 
        if(worksForThreads[x] == null)
            worksForThreads[x] = new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray()
        worksForThreads[x].add(singleOrder)
        x = (x+1) % threadPoolSize
    }

    List<Future> futures = worksForThreads.collect({ myWork ->
        println "\t\tPrepare thread with ${myWork.size()} tasks"
        threadPool.submit({ ->
            threadClosure myWork
        } as Callable )
    })

    //Start thread and collect result
    futures.each{
        def threadResult = it.get()
        println "\t\tThread result ${threadResult}"
        totQuantity = totQuantity+threadResult
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    println "Error during thread works ${e}"                    
}finally{
    threadPool.shutdown()
}
```

So, the code should be fine, but during the thread's execution I get these errors:

```
[pool-9-thread-2] [tenant 0] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Table 'MySchema.MyTable' doesn't exist
```

and

```
Error during thread works java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; 
SQL [select this_.id as id24_0_, this_.code as code24_0_, this_.description as descript3_24_0_, this_.incr as incr24_0_, this_.is_default as is5_24_0_, this_.lang as lang24_0_, this_.last_updated as last7_24_0_, this_.min as min24_0_, this_.name as name24_0_, this_.ordasc as ordasc24_0_, this_.parent_id as parent11_24_0_, this_.parent_mult as parent12_24_0_, this_.prod_code as prod13_24_0_, this_.status as status24_0_, this_.unit_name as unit15_24_0_ 
from MyTable this_ where this_.code=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

I think that the problem is with the tenant scope. I thought to use a service for getting all data from DB, but I want know if there is a way to get the right tenant scope in a thread or to pass it.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

I have find out a solution. Basically the multitenant plugin fetch the tennants by a database table:

So in the Config.groovy I have

```
tenant {
  mode = "singleTenant"
  datasourceResolver.type = "db"
}
```

And the DataSource.groovy provide for each environment the right table where find out the tennants:

```
CREATE TABLE `data_source_tenant_map` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `data_source` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'JNDI',
  `mapped_tenant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file_source` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `data_source_secondary` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `db_url` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Url db multitenant',
  `db_username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Username db multitenant',
  `db_password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Password db multitenant',
  `base_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Root of path on fs',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=280 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With this plugin every thread that is not joined with the main thread loses the Hibernate session and so the tenant reference. To obtain the right tenant I used these method:

```
def myTenantKey = my_mapped_tenant_id
TenantUtils.doWithTenant(myTenantKey ) {
    // Do something as usual
}
```

You have to import the TenantUtils class

```
import grails.plugin.multitenant.core.util.TenantUtils
```

I hope it can be useful for someone else!
Bye!